# Magento - Most efficient method of getting a collection count

Tags: magento

I have a helper method in Magento which requires me to get the count of several unrelated collections.  Further to this, i need this information for each product in a category i.e. for each product in the product list view.  So i will potentially be creating lots of collections repeatedly during the product list rendering.

What is the most efficient method of getting the count of a collection, that is, i do not need any data from the models, simply how many models there are.

Is it simply:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/mymodel_collection')->addFilter('myattribute', $value)->count()
```

Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Very good question. From what I found in the source code, this is the fastest option, even though it does the following in Varien_Data_Collection:

```
public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

So it does its usual thing and goes ahead and loads whatever you specified, just like it would do if you iterated over the individual items. No magic SQL `COUNT()` here. The only other methods I've found that have something to do with counting products are `getSelectCountSql()` and `getProductCountSelect()`, but they just return SQL code.

But: the whole EAV thing and Magento's query builder are very smart, so that shouldn't be *that* big of a deal. Also, I would bet that Magento has all kinds of caching going on.

**So in short: yes, it is the fastest option to count the number of products in a product collection.**

Comment: -1: This is not fastest. The opposite is the case. On large collections this just crashes PHP due to memory limit so it takes up to an infinite amount of more time compared with the `getSize()` method.

Answer (score 73):

For counting items in a collection, use the `getSize()` method:

```
$collection->getSize();
```

**Never** use the php `count()` function or the `count()` method of the collection like this:

```
count($collection)
$collection->count()
```

When you use the `count()` function/method, Magento loads all the items of the collection from the database. On large collections you will have an huge memory usage and possibly issues like `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)`...

Comment: Agree! Thanks for the tip, FLOZz! Do not ever use count(). When working with thousands of items in collection, using count() may cause your store to crash. I found out the hard way..

Comment: I would point out the getSize() actually uses count if _totalRecords is null..
`lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php`  
`lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php`

Comment: count() function used for array, not for the object. while the collection is an object of the specific modal.

if you want to use count() then you need to first convert the collection to an array then after you can use the count() function.

Answer (score 1):

Try as:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/mymodel_collection')->addFieldFilter('myattribute', $value);
$collection->count();
//or
$collection->getSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most efficient way to do this, using built in Magento methods:

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'1'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array('eq'=>'4'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', array('in'=>array('simple')))
                ->getAllIds();
        var_dump(count($ids));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
     * Retrieve collection all items count
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        $this->load();
        if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
        }
        return intval($this->_totalRecords);
    }
```

so getSize() is not more efficient.

Comment: You should probably explain your code a bit more. What file are you looking at? I don't see a function like that anywhere in the app folder in version 1.7.

Comment: Sorry but this is plain wrong, please see the below performance metrics:

Using count():
2014-07-07T12:27:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): Time executed: 0.4933660030365

Using getSize():
2014-07-07T12:28:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Time executed: 0.22210693359375

As you can see, getSize() is significantly more efficient.

Comment: Take an example of the usage inside a loop (say for example you're doing some validation), then multiply the 271.3 milliseconds by the loop iterations. Outside of a loop then yes you're right.